# Data replication between tables with same column names in Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby, rdbms

We have a main table containing all the users from past 1 year no matter whether they are expired or active users containing 70 million user records.

This table is too slow in performance, so we wanted to re-create this table with better indexing and better data type allocation and insert all the records from main table to this new table up to date.

The main table is getting updated/inserted every minute, as its very dynamic.

Without missing any user, I need to insert all the records (70 million) from main table to new table.

Which is the best way to do this? How long will it take to insert 70 million records, asynchronously.

Is there any data replication available?

Is there any1 please suggest me the best solution for this, I need the new table up-to-date faster.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: [this](http://plusbryan.com/mysql-replication-without-downtime) seems relevant. You will need to create a slave to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Will a simple insert from select not solve your problem ?

```
LOCK TABLES `oldtable` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `newtable` SELECT * FROM `oldtable`;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: This will block the application for a while, and also any change after the copy can't be synced.

Comment: @Vatev, yes data can't be synced here. Please any one give me a solution, as my table is growing bigger each day.